# multilanguage using htacces 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, multilingual

I want my website to be multilanguage. Ive made such thing.
I using htaccess mod_rewrite to index.php.
For example when I open the website for the first time, in index.php I'm doing such thing

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.exaple.com/hy");
exit;
```

It's working correctly.
But i want to knows it right method and will it be correctly for seo?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a detailed answer to this in another question on stackoverflow. This should help you get started, let me know if you have any more specific questions:

Stackoverflow: [Internationalization and Search Engine Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828317/internationalization-and-search-engine-optimization/1829730#1829730)

nate